# I cant get image name to summernote textarea

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, summernote

Hi i read lots of pages here and tried everything but i think i am missing something. The code below uploads file to folder but textarea can't get the file name or something, only uploads.  Searched stackoferflow for my same problem, tried all but still couldn't be success.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        height: "300px",
        dialogsInBody: true,
        callbacks: {
            onImageUpload: function(files) {
                uploadFile(files[0]);
            }
        }
    });
});

function uploadFile(file) {
    data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", file);


    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        url: "contentupload.php", //replace with your url
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(url) {
            $('#summernote').summernote("insertImage", url);
            console.log(url);
        }
    });
}

function writeSlug()
{

    var title=  $("#title").val();
    $("#slug").val(convertToSlug(title));
}

function convertToSlug(Text)
{
    return Text
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/ /g,'-')
        .replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'')
        ;
}
```

contentupload.php

```
<?php 
if(empty($_FILES['file']))
{
    exit(); 
}
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
$destinationFilePath = './img-uploads/'.$newfilename ;
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destinationFilePath)){
    echo $errorImgFile;
}
else{
    echo $destinationFilePath;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use summernotes's `editor`, `welEditable` parameter omn funciton inside onImageUpload option

your code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        height: "300px",
        dialogsInBody: true,
        callbacks: {
            onImageUpload: function(files) {
                uploadFile(files[0]);
            }
        }
    });
});

function uploadFile(file) {
    data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", file);


    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        url: "contentupload.php", //replace with your url
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(url) {
            $('#summernote').summernote("insertImage", url);
            console.log(url);
        }
    });
}
```

updated code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#summernote').summernote({
         height: 200,
         callbacks: {
            onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable) {
                uploadFile(files[0], editor, welEditable);
            }
         }
      });

  function uploadFile(file, editor, welEditable) {   //change here
    data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", file);
    $.ajax({
      data: data,
      type: "POST",
      url: "Your URL POST (php)",
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(url) {
        editor.insertImage(welEditable, url);    //and here
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your time, changed with your code but still textarea is empty, only uploads the file . The summernote file is summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js.  and my textarea code is  <textarea id="summernote" class="summernote" name="content"><?php echo $checkData['content']; ?></textarea>